# PHP and mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I have created this function to select data from a database table:

```
function data_users($dbc,$id){    
    $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
    return $r;
}
```

How can I create the same function but this time with prepared statement? After that a usually call the function like this:

```
$result = data_users($dbc,$id);
while ($users_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //do something
}
```

Can I use the same method after the change?

Comment: i don't understand your question.

Comment: i have read it and know how to create a prepared statement but i don't know how to convert it to a function so i can call it several times @jeroen

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can write such a function only of your PHP mysqli is built upon mysqlnd driver. In such a case you can write it like this:

```
function data_users($dbc,$id){    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    return $result->fetch_assoc();
}
```

note that you shouldn't be afraid of the object syntax, it's really simple.

Comment: thank you for your help, can i use object syntax if i use (mysqli_connect) function to connect to database or i need to change it to (new mysqli)

Comment: yes, you can use whatever syntax you want, it doesn't matter.

Comment: what shoud be your real concern is the availability of mysqlnd driver. if it's not available better forget mysqli and start using PDO

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?")) {
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $result);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
```

Comment: can you please send it in procedural style, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Whoever upvoted this answer, please retract your vote. this code won't work.

Comment: look at my answer now. but can i give you an advice, next time read the documentation please, it isnt a codewriting service

Comment: i am so sorry , it's not my intention to be rude. i'm teaching myself how to code and just looking for help understanding few things @Infated